# How to mark a file as originating from an internet location? "This file originated from an internet location"

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, ntfs

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/398268/this-file-originated-from-an-internet-location-how-to-mark-this-file-as-loca) asks how to mark a file as safe (not originated from an internet location). Is there a way to do the opposite? I.e., mark a file as originating from the internet and thus "not safe."

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this How-To Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/70012/what-causes-the-file-downloaded-from-the-internet-warning-and-how-can-i-easily-remove-it/), the information used to determine which files are safe or not is stored in the `Zone.Identifier` ADS (alternate data stream). The text you need to include on there is:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

I'm sure there are plenty of ways of doing so, but one way of editing the ADS is to launch `notepad [filename]:Zone.Identifier`